# How to render a forwarded email in PDF

Tags: email, pdf, forwarding

I have a web api with a webhook to receive emails from Sendgrid (a cloud-based email delivery service). 
My application is converting emails content to PDF documents. Using the a C# library WkHtmlToXSharp.

The code works fine most of the time in production (several hundreds emails a day), but some emails conversion are failing.

My investigation shows that emails that are directly sent to my service are easy to render, they are received with a clean HTML content, for instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ....
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Some other emails have been actually forwarded (with an automatic forwarding rule, or manually forwarded) to my webhook. The email content then look like this:

```
----------- Forwarded message -----------
From: 
....
```

Some others are starting with html tags like a `<div>`, but no doctype, html, body...

I have tested with my own Gmail account, and I see the same alteration when I check the original email content. A direct email contains all necessary html tags, a forwarded email starts with something else that was added by the client mail.
I can't find the actual original email content.

At this point, I don't know how is doing my Gmail client to render emails that have been forwarded to me, as if it knew the original html code, without containing this original code.
If someone could give more explanation about email content, and its alteration when forwarded, maybe I could reproduce it in my application.

Any tips would be great.